# Android biblioteca Xzing (ler código de barras) com fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Minha aplicação funcionava perfeitamente com o Zxing, após implementar fragment, a leitura de código de barras parou de funcionar.  Tentei configurar o retorno no fragment, na activity...  mas não tive sucesso.  Alguém conseguiu fazer essa implementação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chamada:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "ONE_D_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Recepção:

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    if (requestCode == 0){
        if (resultCode ==  Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");


        }
        else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Scan unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
}
```

Aqui funciona perfeitamente!

Comment: Thiago, você está fazendo essa chamada dentro do fragment?  Qual a versão do Zxing você está usando?  Vlw pela ajuda.

Comment: Versão: zxing-android-minimal:1.2.1. Exatamente, faço dentro de um Fragment. Ao clicar em um botão ele chamada dentro de um OnClickListener, que está em um android.app.Fragment

Comment: Thiago, vou testar e retorno.  Obrigado pela ajuda.